# How do I use string interpolation with string literals?

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I'm trying to do something like

```
string heading = $"Weight in {imperial?"lbs":"kg"}"
```

Is this doable somehow?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should add `()` because `:` is used also for `string` formatting:

```
string heading = $"Weight in {(imperial ? "lbs" : "kg")}";
```

Answer (score 14):

Interpolated strings can contain formatting definitions which are separated from the variable name by colons.

```
string formatted = $"{foo:c5}"; // 5 decimal places
```

Since the conditional operator (`?:`) also uses a colon, you have to use braces to make it clear for the compiler that you don't want a format specifier:

```
string heading = $"Weight in {(imperial?"lbs":"kg")}";
```

Comment: Right an precise explanation, +1

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks!